# How to set WindowsTerminal as default terminal in Neovim?

Tags: terminal, windows-10, neovim

I am running windows10. In neovim, when I start terminal using :term command, it opens command prompt by default. Is there a way to add configuration so that :term opens WindowsTerminal instead?

what I tried: when I run :term command, in the status line I see `term://d:\scoop\apps\neovim\current\bin//20576:c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` I tried replacing the path to cmd with path to windows-terminal without success. `term://d:\scoop\apps\neovim\current\bin//20576:d:\scoop\apps\windows-terminal\current\windowsterminal.exe`